# Jetty: war + additional classpath dir

Tags: jetty, classpath, jetty-8

I'm running a war file a.war with jetty using such code:

```
WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setWar("a.war");
context.setContextPath("/controller");
handlers.addHandler(context);
```

I need to add a system-wide directory with keystore to classpath. When I just copy it inside WAR/classes it works. But when I specify it using:

```
-Djetty.class.path=...\security
```

(dir with keystores) - it fails with because keystore is not available on classpath. Is it possible in jetty to use war + additional classpath lib?
Thanks!